# R apply a user-defined function to all rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I am struggling to make loop through the rows of a column in a dataframe and then use the current row to define arguments that will be used in a function. Here is the sample dataframe:

```
df <- 
structure(list(child = c("A268", "A268497", "A268497BOX", "A268497BOX2", 
"A268497BOX218", "A277", "A277A79", "A277A79091", "A277A790911", 
"A277A79091144", "A492", "A492586", "A492586BOX", "A492586BOX1", 
"A492586BOX144", "A492A69", "A492A69027", "A492A690271", "A492A69027144", 
"A492A6902715K", "A492A6902719Y", "A492A690271BH", "A492A690271BI", 
"A492A690271CQ", "A492A690271CS", "A492A690271CT", "A492A690271CU", 
"A492A690271CV", "A492A690271CW", "A492A690271CX", "A492A690271CY", 
"A492A690271DA", "A492A69028", "A492A690281", "A492A69028144", 
"A492A69402", "A492A694021", "A492A69402144", "A492A70", "A492A70033", 
"A492A700331", "A492A70033144", "A492A700332", "A492A70033244", 
"A492A70034", "A492A700341", "A492A70034144", "A492A70035", "A492A700351", 
"A492A70035144"), clvl = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 
5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6), parent = c("A", 
"A268", "A268497", "A268497BOX", "A268497BOX2", "A", "A277", 
"A277A79", "A277A79091", "A277A790911", "A", "A492", "A492586", 
"A492586BOX", "A492586BOX1", "A492", "A492A69", "A492A69027", 
"A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", 
"A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", 
"A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A690271", "A492A69", 
"A492A69028", "A492A690281", "A492A69", "A492A69402", "A492A694021", 
"A492", "A492A70", "A492A70033", "A492A700331", "A492A70033", 
"A492A700332", "A492A70", "A492A70034", "A492A700341", "A492A70", 
"A492A70035", "A492A700351"), plvl = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5
)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

My goal is to generate this:

[image]

I tried to do this with a loop and using different versions of `apply` function inside the loop, but I could not get it right. Here, I need to define that x and y will be the `child` and `pathString` from the current row every time I iterate. Is there a clean and easy way to do this?

```
df[] <- apply(df,1,function(x,y) sub(x,y,x))
```

Comment: what is the logic to create `pathString` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number of characters in `child` (or `pathString`) would keep on increasing as shown in the data shared one way is to use `purrr::accumulate` which allows to take input from previous output and apply it by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(nchar(child)) < 0))) %>%
  mutate(ans = purrr::accumulate(pathString, ~sub(".*(/.*)",paste0(.x, "\\1"),.y))) 

#   child         pathString        gr ans               
#   <chr>         <chr>          <int> <chr>             
# 1 A268          A/268              1 A/268             
# 2 A268497       A268/497           1 A/268/497         
# 3 A268497BOX    A268497/BOX        1 A/268/497/BOX     
# 4 A268497BOX2   A268497BOX/2       1 A/268/497/BOX/2   
# 5 A268497BOX218 A268497BOX2/18     1 A/268/497/BOX/2/18
# 6 A277          A/277              2 A/277             
# 7 A277A79       A277/A79           2 A/277/A79         
# 8 A277A79091    A277A79/091        2 A/277/A79/091     
# 9 A277A790911   A277A79091/1       2 A/277/A79/091/1   
#10 A277A79091144 A277A790911/44     2 A/277/A79/091/1/44
```

Kept the `gr` column of group in the final output to clarify how the groups are created.

---

We can implement the same logic in base R as well using `Reduce`

```
apply_fun <- function(x, y) sub(".*(/.*)", paste0(x, "\\1"), y)

df$ans <- with(df, ave(pathString, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(nchar(child)) < 0)), 
FUN = function(x) Reduce(apply_fun, x, accumulate = TRUE)))
```

Comment: so `df` must be sorted? The real `df `has more than 35k row, I will check your answer tomorrow and will get back to you

Comment: @Ibo Yes. This is what I came up with looking at the expected output. There isn't any logic shared on how to reach to output.

Comment: I tried it with a more extensive data sample and it was not generating the right output. I actually went one step back and edited the data sample so that you can have access to both child and parent values with their level (not sure it can help) if you apply your answer you will see that where `gr` resets at any level that is not level 2 the forward slashes are not created properly, plus in some cases it adds segments from above rows while we are only allowed to add forward slashes to the values. This is to create a path so that I can create `data.tree`

Comment: this is the original post that was not answered by anyone. Maybe there was a better way to get to the final answer, but I could get to here so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870536/r-data-tree-create-a-new-column-for-hierarchy-path-in-a-tree-structure-table

Comment: I managed to find a solution, but I am sure there is a smarter way!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done using the following code block, but the loop takes 75-80 seconds, I guess there could be a faster way:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(df5)) {

  x=df5[row,2] #child
  y=df5[row,3] #pathString
  g=df5[row,c('gr')]

  df5$pathString[df5$gr==g] <- sub(x,y,df5$pathString[df5$gr==g])
  df5$child[df5$gr==g] <- sub(x,y,df5$child[df5$gr==g])

}
```

Note that `gr` was populated based on `clvl=2`:

```
library(zoo)
df4$gr <- ifelse(df4$clvl==2,df4$child,NA)
df4$gr <- na.locf(df4$gr)
```

and this is how `df4` is made:

```
df4 <- sqldf("select  *, parent || replace(child,parent,'/') AS pathString FROM df ORDER BY child")
```